# How can I use Puppeteer to stream of data from network requests instead of full response?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

```
    page.on('response', async (response) => {
        const url = response.url();
        if (url.includes("/api/answer")) {
            response.text().then((text) => { // Returns full data
                res.send(text); // I want to stream this
            })
```

`/api/infer/answe` this API returns streams of data.

Currently, the retrieved data is sent as a single response using res.send(text). However, I want to modify this behavior and stream the data instead of sending it as a single response.

I looked through puppeteer documentation and searched through internet extensively. I couldn't find any answers to fix this.

Comment: Is the original response a stream?

Comment: @ggorlen yes. Original response is a stream